# Boost translate with memory leaks (ver 1.65.1)

Tags: c++, boost, valgrind, translate

I tried to analyze a simple program like this with valgrind

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    generator gen;
    gen.add_messages_path(".");
    gen.add_messages_domain("hello");

    locale::global(gen("de_DE.UTF-8"));
    cout.imbue(locale());

    cout << translate("Hello World") << endl;
}
```

It returns with a list of problems :

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
==8895==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8895==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8895==      possibly lost: 1,376 bytes in 4 blocks
==8895==    still reachable: 67,954 bytes in 253 blocks
==8895==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==8895==                         newarray           : 14,440 bytes in 29 blocks
```

Why ist this happening ? How can I clear memory before exiting the program ?

One of problems to keep the post short:

```
==8895== 1,376 bytes in 4 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 202 of 212
==8895==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8895==    by 0x643D6B6: icu_60::UnicodeString::allocate(int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x643F3A8: icu_60::UnicodeString::cloneArrayIfNeeded(int, int, signed char, int**, signed char) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x643F940: icu_60::UnicodeString::doAppend(char16_t const*, int, int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x64AD66D: icu_60::SimpleFormatter::format(char16_t const*, int, icu_60::UnicodeString const* const*, icu_60::UnicodeString&, icu_60::UnicodeString const*, signed char, int*, int, UErrorCode&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x64AD83B: icu_60::SimpleFormatter::formatAndAppend(icu_60::UnicodeString const* const*, int, icu_60::UnicodeString&, int*, int, UErrorCode&) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x64AD915: icu_60::SimpleFormatter::format(icu_60::UnicodeString const&, icu_60::UnicodeString const&, icu_60::UnicodeString&, UErrorCode&) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x5FD629E: icu_60::SimpleDateFormat::construct(icu_60::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_60::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_60::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x5FD700D: icu_60::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(icu_60::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_60::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_60::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x5FD05C9: icu_60::DateFormat::create(icu_60::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_60::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_60::Locale const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60.2)
==8895==    by 0x4EE389B: boost::locale::impl_icu::icu_formatters_cache::icu_formatters_cache(icu_60::Locale const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.65.1)
==8895==    by 0x4EE3B47: std::locale boost::locale::impl_icu::install_formatting_facets<char>(std::locale const&, boost::locale::impl_icu::cdata const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.65.1)
==8895== 
==8895== 1,904 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 203 of 212
==8895==    at 0x4C3217F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8895==    by 0x4EE3B39: std::locale boost::locale::impl_icu::install_formatting_facets<char>(std::locale const&, boost::locale::impl_icu::cdata const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.65.1)
==8895==    by 0x4ED3FCC: boost::locale::impl_icu::create_formatting(std::locale const&, boost::locale::impl_icu::cdata const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.65.1)
==8895==    by 0x4ED3504: boost::locale::impl_icu::icu_localization_backend::install(std::locale const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.65.1)
==8895==    by 0x4E988E8: boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::impl::actual_backend::install(std::locale const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.65.1)
==8895==    by 0x4E9482B: boost::locale::generator::generate(std::locale const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.65.1)
==8895==    by 0x4E95006: boost::locale::generator::generate(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.65.1)
==8895==    by 0x109E01: boost::locale::generator::operator()(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const (in a.out)
```

I expected a clear memory on program exit

Comment: Judging by the string `icu_formatters_cache` it's probably a cache of some kind. Have you looked in the API if there is a way to clear the cache?

Comment: I tried to remove the localization backends localization_backend_manager::global().remove_all_backends(); Also tried to clear cache / paths / domains of boost generator. No change.

Comment: Boost developers on this topic: [Not a bug/problem. There is nothing you can do.](https://groups.google.com/g/boost-developers-archive/c/7xJF5OE9cEA)

Comment: The answer to this would be for boost to provide a `freeres` function for Valgrind to call.

Answer (score -1):

There is generally the problem with cleanups of globals/statics -- the compiler can't know whether something might still be used.

As such, using globals/statics sometimes use wrappers to DEFEAT the automatic cleanup, like so:

```
Foo& Foo::get()
{
   static Foo& instance=*new Foo();
   return instance;
}
```

That way, your instance will never get deleted. It's not a memory leak either.

Chances are that this what you're seeing.

Why is this needed? During cleanup, something could still be using that Foo-instance, even after the compiler has deleted it. While you could try to work around this by using `shared_ptr` or something similar, you're just making things more complicated than they need to be: once the process terminates, the Foo instance is gone anyway.

I also do something similar with persistent threads -- that is, threads that are launched, and then stick around for the lifetime of the program. I don't add a "quit" procedure to them; they die anyway when the program quits.

Comment: Don't use singletons. Cleanup of things like this gets complicated when `dlopen()` and `dlclose()` are used. I recommend that you try to minimize bad practices like this (and suppress those that can't be avoided). If everyone leaves a mess behind you will find it hard to deal with genuine 'reachable' memory that ought to have been freed.

Comment: Why would you use the memory leak operator when `Foo& Foo::get() { static Foo instance; return instance; }` would be just as fine - but better actually not a leak